# Multiple xml files in one activity - Android application

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have just started developing an android app, so i'm kinda new to java and xml.

I have my frontpage, activity_main.xml and the java file, MainActivity.java

On the activity_main.xml page i have inserted a button. When I click on this button it goes to page2.xml

On page2.xml i have another button. The user is supposed to be redirected to page3.xml when he clicks the button. But nothing appears when the button on page2.xml is clicked.

Following is button code on my activity_main.xml file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/page2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/knap" />
```

This is the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.testing;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button  page2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 



        page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.page2); 



        page2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.minapp.PAGE2"));
            }
        });  


    }
}
```

I have also 'page2.java'

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 

public class page2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page2);

    }

}
```

And finally my AndroidManifest.xml file where i have these activities,

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".page2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.minapp.PAGE2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So what do i do when i want to see page3.xml when i click the button on page2.xml

Hope you guys can help me, thank you!

Comment: You don't do anything with the button in `page2`.?.

Comment: you didn't add clicklistener for page2's button.

Comment: just added a clicklistender for page2's button, but it still doesn't work. Do you think there is something wrong with this: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ????  @abbath

Answer (score 0):

try switching this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.minapp.PAGE2"));
```

with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, page2.class);
this.startActivity (intent);
```

And your manifest has a little too much information, you dont need intent filter that point to the actviity itself:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".page2"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: If you liked this answer please mark it as answered with the check mark on the left ^^